# Power apps how to display time in an hours:minutes:seconds format

Tags: function, time, powerapps

I am developing an app in power apps. I need to be able to display the digital time in `hours:minutes:seconds`. Using `Now()` will only display `hours:minutes`.

How do I add seconds to the display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Text Function](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/tutorials/function-text/) to convert the date/time value that you get from the [Now function](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/tutorials/function-now-today-istoday/) with the format that you want:

```
Text(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
```

If you want the time to be continuously updated, then you need to use a Timer control to set a variable, and use that variable in the Text function.

For example, on the Timer's OnTimerEnd property, you'd have something like

```
UpdateContext({now: Now()})
```

And on the label you'd have

```
Text(now, "hh:mm:ss")
```

Notice that the timer will not run in authoring mode, so you need to preview the app ("play" button in the top-right corner) to see it in action. It works fine in the published app.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into my app and it does show the hours - minutes - seconds however it is not automatically increasing the seconds as I look at it now it just displays 11:00:05 and not increasing. Any idea how I can get it to automatically go up

Comment: Updated the answer with more information about this scenario.

Comment: Thank-you your code worked brilliantly, I just had to make some tweaks like putting  UpdateContext({now: Now()}) in the OnTimerEnd and OnTimerStart, Then I had to toggle autostart.